# Swift: UIApplication.shared is undefined during app launch, but it works?

Tags: swift, uikit

So check out the following code. We're only concerned about the init function here, body is standard and unimportant.

```swift
@main
struct SomeApp: App {
    init() {
        print(UIApplication.shared) // Crash = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        ...
    }
}
```

App crashes at the print statement. Okay. Fine. The world doesn't exist yet... or so it seems.

Now try this...

```swift
@main
struct SomeApp: App {
    init() {
        print(UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible) // prints false!!!
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        ...
    }
}
```

The app DOESN'T crash and the print statement prints false.

Breakpoint the print statement and check in the debugger....

```
(lldb) po UIApplication.shared
 <uninitialized>
(lldb) po UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible
false
(lldb) po UIApplication.shared
 <uninitialized>
```

Can someone explain the black magic that seems to be going on here??? Does dynamic dispatch have some sort of secret understanding with UIApplication???

Answer (score 3):

So obtained the answer in another [context](https://forums.swift.org/t/uiapplication-shared-is-undefined-during-app-launch-but-it-works/60859). To quote:

UIApplication.shared is declared to return UIApplication, so if you're accessing that value in a context where it's actually giving you a nil reference from the UIKit side, that's going to cause problems for Swift (because on the Swift side of things, we won't be performing any nil checks).

But UIApplication is also an Objective-C class, and so an access like UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible is going to become an Objective-C message sent to UIApplication.shared.

And it's perfectly valid in Objective-C to send messages to nil and get back 'reasonable' values for many return types...

Such as false for Bool values.

Comment: Exactly (I was about to formulate something similar :) – Side note: If you replace `print(UIApplication.shared)` by `NSLog("%@", UIApplication.shared)` then you'll get “(null)” as output, without a crash.